# How to append the axios result to vuejs datatables?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to vuejs. I have a laravel+vue project in which I had used vuejs datatables for displaying all the users. I am stuck on why the data is not appending to the datatable :data property and I also tried to display data in `<div v-for="user in users">{{ user.name }}</div>` tag with for loop then it is displaying but when I used for loop in datatable then loop doesn't stops and also there is no error in the console. Please tell me the solution and thanks in advance. Here is my code.

UserController.php

```
public function index()
{
    return response()->json(['users' => User::all()], 200);
}
```

UserComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <datatable :columns="columns" :data="users"></datatable>
</template>

<script>
    export default()
    {
        data()
        {
           return {
             columns: [
               {label: 'id', field: 'id'},
               {label: 'Name', field: 'name'},
               {label: 'Email', field: 'email'}
             ],
             users: []
        };
     },
     mounted()
     {
       this.getUsers();
     },
     methods:
     {
       getUsers()
         {
            axios.get('api/user')
                .then(res => this.users = res.data.users)
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
         },
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please share some more code. Are you using VueJsDatatable as your datatable? Are you registering the component globally?
Also `<div v-for="user in users">user.name</div>` is not working because `user.name` should be `{{ user.name }}`.

Comment: Yes it is {{user.name}} not user.name, sorry for that it is a typing mistake and yes I am using VueJsDatatable as my datatable and the componenet is registered globally in app.js

Comment: Do you get anything if you `console.log` the response?

Comment: yes I had got all the data from database in the form of array of objects.